# Cannot extract jpg from pdf using pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am trying to extract a jpg image from a pdf file. Please take a look at a reproducible example:
https://codepen.io/thomas-kertsalis/pen/YzpYwYo?editors=1111

```
window.objs=[];
   pdfjsLib.getDocument(sURL).promise
     .then(pdf => {
     for(var i=1;i<(pdf.numPages+1);i++){
                      pdf.getPage(i).then(function(page) {
                        page.getOperatorList().then(function (ops) {
                           for (var i=0; i < ops.fnArray.length; i++) {
                             let currentElement=ops.argsArray[i];
                              if(ops.fnArray[i] == pdfjsLib.OPS.paintImageXObject) {
                                window.objs.push(ops.argsArray[i][0])
                                let   imageName=ops.argsArray[i][0];
                                page.objs.get(imageName, function(img) {  
                                const content = img.data;
                                var newB64 = btoa(content);
                                document.getElementById("my-img").src =
                                'data:image/png;base64,'+newB64;
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
      }
    }
```

Comment: The data you're `btoa`ing is comma-separated ASCII integers, not binary data...

Comment: Also, even so there's no guarantee that an image in a PDF is actually JPEG – it could be JBIG, CCITT, some other formats.

Comment: If you don't necessarily need to do this in the browser, or in JavaScript at all, the `pdfimages` tool from Poppler does this handily.